# Object has not method (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, function

I have this in a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    jQuery.fn.SaveAdd = function(titulo,contenido,tags) {
       // code
    }
});
```

And I imported the js to the HTML document, and I called the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iSave").click(function(){
        // declaration of vars instead of this line
        $(this).SaveAdd(title,content,tags);    
    });
});
```

and I have the error:  has not the method SaveAdd. BUT when u use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // declaration of vars instead of this line
        $(this).SaveAdd(title,content,tags);    
});
```

The function runs rightly :S i dont know what is wrong...

Comment: are you trying to create a jquery plugin?

Comment: You're defining the plugin when the DOM is ready. You should read up about plugin authoring here > http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have given to us, you seem to be creating a plugin for jQuery, and it would be somewhat like this:

```
(function($) {

     $.fn.SaveAdd = function(titulo,contenido,tags) {
         //your great code
     };

})(jQuery);
```

I have here a sample for you

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.SaveAdd = function(titulo, contenido, tags) {
        alert(titulo);
        alert(contenido);
        alert(tags);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#iSave").click(function() {
        $(this).SaveAdd("hehe", "hahha", "hohoo");
    });
});
```

See how it works here http://jsfiddle.net/K4Tfg/

Have a read about this and it will surely solve your problem: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: well... im new in jQuery, im not enough to create a plug-in, (not 2day), i readed how to make functions and use it... i made another function that i used in other page and works, but i tested the same function for this page and has the same error.

Comment: sure, let me type what the console says:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'SaveAdd'

Comment: I updated my answer and given you a fiddle code so you can see how it works

Comment: @Mahan sorry i dont know if i have to tag or just type.

Comment: says Error: Unexpected token '(' <script>
function ($) {
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

    $.fn.SaveAdd = function (titulo, contenido, tags) {
        alert(titulo);
        alert(contenido);
        alert(tags);
    };

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#iSave").click(function () {

        $(this).SaveAdd("hehe", "hahha", "hohoo");
    });

});</script>

Comment: did you already saw my fiddle? did you loaded the jquery first then the plugin code then your event handler?

Comment: yeah, jQuery file is in head, that in the body

Comment: @Mahan please look at this: http://i1233.photobucket.com/albums/ff394/ikuriel/test1_zpsb4f39ce1.jpg  and http://i1233.photobucket.com/albums/ff394/ikuriel/test1_zpsc5cfb663.png

Comment: @Mahan did u see the images? thats a very rare Error code... all the syntax is right typed and positioned...

Comment: well... i just gonna take a break ... programming all the night... no solution for this rare Error, thank you anyways for all that answered the question.

Comment: @user2038286 it seems to be a very isolated case that occurs only in your current codes, please check it very carefully or start at very beginning where you will try the codes above then put your existing codes one by one

Comment: i only could access to the "Object" ussing Aloha.ready()... maybe jQuery and Aloha have conflicts and i didnt try "jquery noconflict" maybe that is the solution too. thank you all. @Mahan

Answer (score 3):

Plugins should not be wrapped in a `document.ready` handler - that'll defer the addition of the function to jQuery until too late.  The normal pattern is:

```
(function($) {

     $.fn.SaveAdd = function(...) {
         ...
     };

})(jQuery);
```

You don't *have* to use `$` as the alias for jQuery within the plugin module, but it is the usual convention.

**EDIT** I see that your real problem appears to be use of a library (Aloha) that loads up its own version of jQuery dynamically (using requirejs) and doesn't export it in the normal way.   As mentioned in the comments, this is why your error message reported problems with `[object Object]` -  a clear indication that `$(...)` was not returning a jQuery object.

See http://aloha-editor.org/guides/dependencies.html for more information on how to resolve those conflicts.

Comment: i gonna try this way thanks for answer, ill tell what happened in 5 min

Comment: Update: i used that sintaxis to make the function, i called the function like i comented in the 1st post, and does not work, same error :S

Comment: has not the method SaveAdd

Comment: @user2038286 what "has not the method"?  If you've used the above code correctly (and also loaded jQuery) then jQuery _does_ have that method.  In comments to the other answer you said `[object Object]` which means that you're trying to call `.SaveAdd` on something that _isn't_ a jQuery collection.

Comment: i loaded jQuery, this is the code of testing by Mahan:http://i1233.photobucket.com/albums/ff394/ikuriel/test1_zpsc5cfb663.png AND this is the result in my PC: http://s1233.beta.photobucket.com/user/ikuriel/media/test1_zpsb4f39ce1.jpg.html

Comment: @user2038286 yes, I already saw those on the other answer.  There must be something else at fault.  Please show the `head` of your HTML.

Comment: i only could access to the "Object" ussing Aloha.ready()... maybe jQuery and Aloha have conflicts and i didnt try "jquery noconflict" maybe that is the solution too. thank you all. @Alnitak

Comment: So, exactly as I said, your call to `$(...)` wasn't producing a jQuery object, which is why I asked you to include your `<head>` - it would have helped a _lot_ to know that you were using Aloha.